# Android facebook sdk appinvites AppInviteDialog white screen

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fbsdkappinvitecontent

Hi im having this problem, when i try to send facebook appinvites from my android app it just hangs on this white dialog forever: [image: white dialog]. I've tried in emulators and real devices and it  just keeps doing the same. I followed this guide:
 https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/android . Its wierd because at start i wasn't having this problem, it was opening fine and could see facebook friends and send the invitations but suddenly it just stopped working. I've been searching for a solution and cant find anything.
Some info:

- Im using facebook-android-sdk:4.20.0
- My call to the sdk:
  `@Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  ```
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_fbfriends);
  FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);
  callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

  if (AppInviteDialog.canShow()) {
      /* handle the result */
      AppInviteContent content = new AppInviteContent.Builder()
              .setApplinkUrl("facebook generated link to myapp")
              .build();
      AppInviteDialog.show(this, content);
  }
  ```

  }`
- The logcat when i call AppInviteDialog.show(this, content):

> I/cr_LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 6 ms (timestamps 8392-8398)                                                   
>   I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "52.0.2743.100", actual native library version number "52.0.2743.100" 
>   I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "52.0.2743.100", actual native library version number "52.0.2743.100" 
>   I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(143)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0                       
>   I/cr_BrowserStartup: Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true                                                           
>   W/cr_media: Requires BLUETOOTH permission                                                                                        
>   I/cr_DRP: No DRP key due to exception:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.webview.chromium.Drp                         
>   W/cr_AwContents: onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring                                                     
>   I/cr_Ime: ImeThread is not enabled.                                                                                              
>   I/Choreographer: Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.                              
>   E/libEGL: validate_display:99 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)                                                                       
>   I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es                                                                     
>   [ 03-11 08:03:08.849  2642: 3328 D/         ] HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x6fff73f04ac0, tid 3328     
>   D/FA: Connected to remote service                                                                                                
>   I/art: Do full code cache collection, code=123KB, data=109KB                                                                     
>   I/art: Starting a blocking GC JitCodeCache                                                                                       
>   I/art: After code cache collection, code=113KB, data=74KB                                                                        
>   W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 2642                               
>   W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread                                                                 
>   I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=121KB, data=88KB                                                                   
>   I/art: After code cache collection, code=121KB, data=88KB                                                                        
>   I/art: Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB                                                                                   
>   W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread                                                                 
>   W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread                                                                 
>   W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread                                                                 
>   W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread

( CONTINUES UNTIL :)

> I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(155)] "Uncaught Error: Minified exception occurred; use the non-minified dev environment for the full error message and additional helpful warnings.", source: https://m.facebook.com/connect/dialog/MPlatformAppInvitesJSDialog?app_id=MYAPPID&method_args=%7B%22destination%22%3A%22facebook%22%2C%22app_link_url%22%3A%22https%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Ffb.me%5C%2Fmyapplink%22%7D&bridge_args=%7B%22action_id%22%3A%22b60bf3e2-7b08-4fa0-b2c3-a4839b40b440%22%7D&display=touch&android_key_hash=MYAPPKEYHASH (155) 
>   W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread                                                                                               
>   W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread                                                                                               
>   W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread                                                                                               
>   I/art: Compiler allocated 6MB to compile void android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals()                                                                    
>   W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread                                                                                               
>   W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread                                                                                               
>   W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread                                                                                               
>   W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread                                                                                               
>   W/art: Suspending all threads took: 16.507ms                                                                                                                   
>   I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 19(592B) AllocSpace objects, 3(18MB) LOS objects, 17% free, 19MB/23MB, paused 8.410ms total 43.175ms  
>   W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread                                                                                               
>   W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread                                                                                               
>   W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread                                                                                               
>   I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 23(664B) AllocSpace objects, 2(12MB) LOS objects, 13% free, 25MB/29MB, paused 7.096ms total 37.376ms  
>   W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread                                                                                               
>   W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread                                                                                               
>   W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread

And then it just keepgoing like that forever.

- My facebook app setup is currently live and available to the public.

Please let me know if there is any other information i can provide and thank you.

Comment: have you got the solution ?

Comment: I just checked a bug report i did and apparently its a facebook bug and they are already working on it. This is the report link: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/721787828000962/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just checked a bug report i did and apparently its a facebook bug and they are already working on it. This is the report link: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/721787828000962/

Comment: Similar problem in iOS also still loading.....for a while in FBSDKAppInviteDialog