# Android Facebook Invite

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to integrate invite friends functionality to my application. I successfully implemented Facebook SDK and Facebook login but when I try to use code from their documentation:

String appLinkUrl, previewImageUrl;

```
appLinkUrl = "https://fb.me/#####";
previewImageUrl = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/xBD-lKB1aa2p6UTfDcU7i0Q-lQa0vEJalYPqTwJcZv7kyf49iXaNFh0ZwsBR";

if (AppInviteDialog.canShow()) {
AppInviteContent content = new AppInviteContent.Builder()
            .setApplinkUrl(appLinkUrl)
            .setPreviewImageUrl(previewImageUrl)
            .build();
AppInviteDialog.show(this, content);
}
```

I get some weird error (popup appear but it's not disappearing and is only showing white screen with spinner loading) and I got this error:

```
03-13 10:35:16.567 3893-3893/com.fbdemoappI/chromium: 
[INFO:CONSOLE(155)]       
 "Uncaught Error: Minified exception occurred; use the non-minified dev environment for the full error message and additional helpful warnings.", source: https://m.facebook.com/connect/dialog/MPlatformAppInvitesJSDialog?app_id=567834300069406&method_args=%7B%22destination%22facebook%22%2C%22preview_image_url%22%3A%22https%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Flh3.googleusercontent.comD-lKB1aa2p6UTfDcU7i0Q-lQa0vEJalYPqTwJcZv7kyf49iXaNFh0ZwsBRUOyr71I%3Dw300-rw%22%2C%22app_link_url%22%3A%22https%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Ffb.me%5C%2F653314188188083%22%7D&bridge_args=%7B%22action_id%22%3A%22d4cf30db-8610-49c1-9b24-2e7a02d7c072%22%7D&display=touch&android_key_hash=XClByNT0DDJvruTU5ocwA8AW4-I%0A (155)
```

Comment: Same problem in iOS also still loading.....for a while in FBSDKAppInviteDialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same error and It's a facebook bug and they are working on it. For reference Kindly go through the link https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/721787828000962/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42736554/android-facebook-sdk-appinvites-appinvitedialog-white-screen